# TextColor property of Label in XamarinForms not working on Android

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have followed all documentation put out by Microsoft on how to utilize the TextColor property and cannot seem to get it to change on Android for the life of me. I have set it at the XAML level with the following code `<Label x:Name="lblError" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" TranslationY="150" TextColor="Red"/>` to no avail. I've also tried setting it in the C# side of things as well with the following code as well to no avail.

```
case Device.Android:
   lblError.Text = "*Please enter a valid code";
   lblError.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
   lblError.TextColor = Color.Red;
   break;
```

Any help would be appreciated. The documentation seems straightforward, but clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Make sure to do a full uninstall / clean / rebuild when something like that happens. I have had it cache UI stuff for me before and didn't realize it wasn't applying changes.

Comment: What version on XF you are using?

Comment: I have done a full uninstall/clean/rebuild as well. Sorry, should've put that in the description as well.

Comment: I am on the most recent version of XF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the folder `bin` and `obj` .Then clean and rebuild your project.There seems to be no problem with your code.I use the following code and it works fine both on Android and iOS.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
               TextColor="Red"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
 </StackLayout>
```

if it still could not work,you could use CustomRenderer to change its color :

custom a label in your forms project :

```
public class MyLablel:Label
{

}
```

custom label renderer in your Android.Project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyLablel), typeof(MyLablelRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class MyLablelRenderer:LabelRenderer
   {
      public MyLablelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
       {
       }
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
       {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);
         if (Control != null)
          {              
            Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
          }

       }

    }
}
```

then use in your page.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:MyLablel Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed it for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Actually intriguingly, it fixed it in the designer, but not the actual app. And I did completely uninstall the app from my test phone and re-install it. Do some android phones not support colored text?

Comment: I am actually experiencing this with almost any color that isn't a background color.

Comment: @NathanGeranis It's really weird. Everything works on my side.If it really doesn't work, you can use customrender to change its color.See my update.

Comment: It appears that it's maybe just an issue with the phone I'm using to test on? When I use an android emulator, the text color shows up appropriately, but when I deploy to my test phone, the text either shows up as black or white.

Comment: I had the same issue and as @TubaControl mentioned it was related to `High-contrast text` ... Do you know if there are way to omit this behavior ??

Answer (score 1):

On the Android device go to Settings > System > Accessibility and check that 'High-contrast text' is turned off.  Then your label colors should work like in the simulator on Windows.

I had the same problem and just spent two hours troubleshooting.  My vision is quite bad so the 'High-contrast text' option is generally useful but when I made some labels and the text color property didn't seem to work as advertised I found myself confused.

Comment: It is exactly my case ... but what if user will have enabled this option ? How to make Label with Red color anyway ?

Comment: You have to realise that accessibility settings aren't there to make your work difficult.  They're there to enable extraordinary people to interact with there computer, phone etc. Even if you could override these settings it would be very bad practice.  If something like a company logo needs to be a specific color to fit the brand then consider using a graphic instead, just make sure it has an alt tag (or Xamarin equivalent) for screen readers.