# Xamarin.Forms Label TextColor Not Applying

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-color, textcolor

I am experiencing an issue with setting the TextColor property for a Xamarin.Forms Label. Despite specifying a color, the text remains transparent. I have tried the following:

Ensured there are no conflicting parent styles affecting the Label.
Checked for platform-specific styles for iOS, Android, and UWP.
Verified that there are no dynamic resource issues.
Here's a simplified version of my XAML:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scroller" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0">
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Label x:Name="label3" TextColor="White" FontSize="30"></Label>
     <Label x:Name="button2" TextColor="Black" Text="   " FontSize="30"></Label>
```

It's the same for `BackgroundColor`

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161428/textcolor-property-of-label-in-xamarinforms-not-working-on-android) out? It might help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Have you set the text property of the label?